# Is it possible to reset CI_JOB_ID to some value in GitLab-CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We've moved to a new gitlab server and CI_JOB_ID is started from 1 here. But we use CI_JOB_ID as a build number, and we want it to start from the last build number (which was on the old gitlab server). Is it possible to reset CI_JOB_ID to some value?

Or maybe there is a better way to generate build number?

Comment: My workaround is to use custom variable `JOB_ID_OFFSET` and to calculate build number as `CI_JOB_ID-JOB_ID_OFFSET`

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but one option would be to modify the GitLab CI with a before_script block that would set a new variable to the value of the CI_JOB_ID plus the offset from the old GitLab server.